# If not MaterializedViews and not secondary indices then what else is the recommended way to query data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have some data in Cassandra. Say

```
create table MyTable {
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    data text,
    updated_on timestamp
}
```

My application in addition to querying this data by primary key id, needs to query it by updated_on timestamp as well. To fulfil the query by time use case I have tried the following.

```
create table MyTable {
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    data text,
    updated_on timestamp,
    updated_on_minute timestamp
}
```

1. Secondary index on the updated_on_minute field. As I understand, secondary indexes are not recommended for high cardinality cases (which is my case, because I could have a lot of data at the same minute mark). Moreover I have data that gets frequently updated, which means the updated_on_minute will keep revving.
2. MaterializedView with updated_on_minute as the partition key and a id as the clustering key. I am on version 3.9 of cassandra and had just begun using these, but alas I find these release notes for 3.11x (https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/NEWS.txt), which declare them purely experimental and not meant for production clusters.

So then what are my options? Do I just need to maintain my own tables to track data that comes in timewise? Would love some input on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always have been the case, create additional table to query by a different partition key.

In your case the table would be

```
create table MyTable_by_timestamp {
    id text,
    data text,
    updated_on timestamp,
    Primary key(updated_on, id)
}
```

Write to both tables mytable_by_timetamp and mytable_by_id. Use the corresponding table to READ from based on the partition key either updated_on or id.

It’s absolutely fine to duplicate data based on the use case (query) it’s trying solve.

**Edited:**

In case there is a fear about huge partition, you can always bucket into smaller partitions. For example the table above could be broken down into

```
create table MyTable_by_timestamp {
    id text,
    data text,
    updated_on timestamp,
    updated_min timestamp,
    Primary key(updated_min, id)
}
```

Here I have chosen every minute as the bucket size. Depending on how many updates you receive, you can change it to seconds (updated_sec) to reduce the partition size further.

Comment: If I duplicate the data, then the partitions become large. So I am likely to create a table with just the dimensions and not the date. You dont see an issue with that do you?

Comment: If you store only the dimensions, then you can't query by date correct? Which I thought was your original question. You can always play with the bucket size or introduce artificial buckets to reduce the partition size.

Comment: Cool, I just needed confirmation that maintaining separate tables at the application level is still the recommended way forward. And seems like it is.